# C# faster way to do sprite animation

Tags: c#, animation, sprite

I'm working on a Winforms app and could use some advice.
I've got several hundred 50x50 sprites that move around on a 2000x2000 playing field over time.
Initially I created it with the sprites being progamatically generated picture boxes that were added to the form and moved around.  It got the job done, but it was flickery and slow.

After quite a bit of googling, it looked like creating a frame buffer and drawing directly to that, then applying the buffer to a static image box on the form seemed to be the way to go.

So I rig all this up, and it ends being much slower than using picture boxes.  It seems to be due to the size of the buffer 2000x2000 (Takes about 100ms to create the buffer each time.)

The code for painting the screen:

```
private void animateAmoebas()
{
    for (int animationStep = 0; animationStep < 100; animationStep = animationStep + animationStepSize)
        {

        Image buffer = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);              
        buffer = imageBKG; //Redraw the grid pattern.                   
        foreach (Amoeba _Amoeba in amoebaPool)//Ameboa is a class object that has AI in it to detirmine the actions of the Amoeba.
            {
                //PBL (PictureBoxLoader) is an object that contains the sprite image, plus the cordinates for that sprite in that frame.
                pbl = _Amoeba.animateSprite(animationStep,pbl);
                drawSprite(pbl, buffer);//Draw the sprite to the buffer
            }               
            refreshScreen(buffer);//Copy the buffer to the picturebox
        }
}


private void drawSprite(PictureBoxLoader pbLoader, Image _buffer) 
{
    using (Graphics formGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_buffer))
    {
        Point imgPoint = new Point(pbLoader.imgX, pbLoader.imgY);
        formGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(pbLoader.imgImage, imgPoint);
    }
}

private void refreshScreen(Image _image)
{         
        pictureBox_BKG.Image = _image;
        this.Refresh();                
}
```

Any suggestions for a better way to do this?

I tried taking a static creating the imagebuffer ahead of time and just redrawing the background to it.  That helps, but it's still dramatically slower than using picture boxes.  Though, admittedly the method above allows for proper transparencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a PictureBox at all.  Just derive from `Control` and override `OnPaint`.  You can draw to your buffer image inside the `OnPaint` and then draw the image to the control.

```
public class SpriteCanvas : Control
{
    private const int AnimationSteps = 100;
    private const int AnimationStepSize = 4;

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
    private Bitmap _buffer;
    private int _animationStep = 0;

    public SpriteCanvas()
    {
        _buffer = new Bitmap(2000, 2000, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 10;

        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            _animationStep += AnimationStepSize;

            if (_animationStep > AnimationSteps)
                _animationStep = 0;

            this.Invalidate();
        };

        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(_buffer))
        {
            // draw sprites based on current _animationStep value
            // g.DrawImage(...)
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_buffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, _buffer.Width, _buffer.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, _buffer.Width, _buffer.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _timer.Dispose();
        _buffer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You have a lot of other problems in your code.  First of all I'm assuming you are drawing everything on the UI thread.  This is a no-no.  You should be calling `Invalidate` on the control when you want it to redraw.  You should do this on a timer.

You also are creating a new Image buffer on each iteration of the loop and you are immediately discarding it without even disposing it:

```
Image buffer = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);              
buffer = imageBKG; //Redraw the grid pattern.
```

The `Bitmap` class implements `IDisposable` and you should always wrap it in a `using` block or call `Dispose` on it when you no longer need it.  In your case you probably only ever want to create 1 bitmap to act as your buffer and you should dispose it when your `Control` is disposed.

Another mistake you are making is calling `Refresh`, this will cause a synchronous paint which in your case will cause your control to freeze.  I don't think you have a good reason for doing this.  Use `Invalidate` instead of `Refresh`.

You also call `Graphics.FromImage` every time you draw a single sprite.  So you are calling this hundreds of times per frame.  Obviously you don't want to do this.  You should only call this once per draw.

Comment: "You also call Graphics.FromImage every time you draw a single sprite"
If I'm drawing hundreds of sprites per frame, how can I avoid this?

I suppose it would make more sense to create a list or something else to send in and have that do all the draws at once, right?

I'll have to play around with this.invalidate.  It breaks with the background worker.

Comment: My code is pretty much complete up until the point where you need to draw a sprite based on the animation step.  Can you be more specific on how you are doing this currently?  I do not understand what your amoebaPool and PictureBoxLoader classes are actually doing.  You should simply has a function that passes a `Graphics` instance and some parameter (either the current animation step, or a value calculated based on that step) to a function which draws the sprite.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a lot to work with.  I'll implement what you have here.  

"First of all I'm assuming you are drawing everything on the UI thread" - That I'm actually using a background worker thread and than passing the refresh call using a delegate.

Comment: @EtanSivad Keep in mind that Refresh draws on the UI thread whereas Invalidate will paint on a separate thread (at least on newer versions of Windows).  Invalidate is also better since Windows will intelligently draw depending on performance.  So on one computer it might draw 10 times in a second, on another computer it might draw 20.  All the while your UI should remain responsive in both cases.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code here.  You said "You can draw to your buffer image inside the OnPaint and then draw the image to the control." 
So it looks like you've got a separate class here.  I can see how to do the sprite drawing inside the framework you've provided.
I don't understand how I tie this back to the  " public partial class Form1 : Form" that is the main form.

Comment: The code above creates a Control in your project called `SpriteCanvas`.  You can add that as a child control to the parent form in code like you would any other Control.  You can also add it using the Visual Studio Windows Forms designer, it should show up in the Toolbox.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  This:
`SpriteCanvas canvas = new SpriteCanvas
        {
            Size = new Size(1000,1000),
            Location = new Point (0,0),
        };` 
plus this: `this.Controls.Add(canvas);`
added it to the form and lets me paint with it.  
It's quick, but it flicker pretty constantly.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: It shouldn't flicker from painting on a timer with invalidate, especially since you are drawing first to a buffer and then drawing the buffer all at once to the screen.  You are effectively double buffering.  Try changing the Bitmap constructor to supply a 3rd argument, `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` (edited in my answer)

Comment: Still flickers.
I'm doing this: 
`Random random = new Random();              
g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.prototype, new Point(random.Next(0, 500),random.Next(0, 500)));`
To get it to draw a random sprite on each pass. Maybe that's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a new Bitmap(2000, 2000) each step of the animation and never reusing them, which will wreck havoc on the garbage collector. Instead, save an instance of your buffer as a member variable and save a blank sprite of the same size. At the beginning of each draw loop, draw the blank sprite onto the buffer, then draw the amoeba sprites.

This can still cause flickering due to inconsistencies between the screen refresh rate and your draw rate. To fix that, use double buffering. Here's some pseudo-C# for a simple double buffered draw method.

```
private Image backBuffer = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);
private Image frontBuffer = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);
private Image clearSprite = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);

// Draws 1 frame
private void Draw()
{
  // Clear the back buffer
  backBuffer.Draw(clearSprite);

  // Draw sprites
  foreach (var sprite in sprites)
  {
    backBuffer.Draw(sprite);
  }

  // Swap buffers
  frontBuffer.Draw(backBuffer);
}
```

You're also running the entire animation without yielding control to another method, so I would also recommend moving to an asynchronous model where you have a drawing manager that is responsible for managing the buffers and is told to run it's draw function on a set interval. Each amoeba should be in control of which frame it's animation is on and it should  be able to draw itself to a buffer when passed one by the draw manager.